# Ports closed on macOS Sierra Can't Use Apple Services -- Terminal Help?

Tags: macos, apple-id, messages, network

**OS:** Sierra 10.12.2
**System:** Macbook11,3 MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013) with a 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7 and 16 GB TAM.

I cannot use Messages to sign into my iMessage account. I get:

> An error occurred during authentication.

This has been for over a month and I have gone to the Apple store and called support. Support passed it to engineering and it faded away. This is the error:

[image]

All of the ports seem to be blocked, or at least they do not show up on a port scan out of Network Utility. When I use `lsof -i | grep http`all I see are Chrome windows which happen to be open.

I left off last time with my pf file being disabled. So that's not it. Any ideas?

Note: I was troubleshooting earlier and made some leeway. This is not the same question as earlier, it has advanced. I am now specifically looking for terminal commands.

Answer (score 1):

Check the ports. This might help -- not sure how to proceed after: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202078

Comment: I am aware of that but still unsure how to open the ports.